# Can't pass object as a reference

Tags: c++, qt

Like in the title.

My goal is to get the object without recreating it,
obviously I could use pointers but

1) I like to keep pointers for factory objects, database handlers etc

2) I want to learn something instead of going the easy way

so theres the code and errors are at the bottom, thanks for your time and advice :)

somewhere out there in code

```
QTcpSocket* socket = (QTcpSocket*)this->sender();
Request request(socket);
Response response(request, this->managerFactory);
```

response.h

```
#ifndef RESPONSE_H
#define RESPONSE_H

#include <QString>
#include "Request.h"
#include "../manager/ManagerFactory.h"

class Response {
public:
    Response(const Request &request, ManagerFactory *managerFactory);
    QString getValue();
private:
    QString generateJsonHeader();
    Request &request;
    ManagerFactory *managerFactory;
};

#endif  /* RESPONSE_H */
```

resonse.cpp

```
#include "Response.h"

Response::Response(const Request &request, ManagerFactory *managerFactory)
{
    this->request = request;
    this->managerFactory = managerFactory;
}
```

request.h

```
#ifndef REQUEST_H
#define REQUEST_H

#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QString>
#include <QMap>

class Request {
public:
    Request(QTcpSocket* socket);
    bool hasParameter(QString paramName);
    QString getParameter(QString paramName);

private:
    void loadParameters(QTcpSocket* socket);
    QMap<QString, QString> parameters;
};

#endif  /* REQUEST_H */
```

request.cpp

```
#include "Request.h"

Request::Request(QTcpSocket* socket)
{
    this->loadParameters(socket);
}
```

and this is the error I am facing

```
source/server/Response.cpp: In constructor ‘Response::Response(const Request&, ManagerFactory*)’:
source/server/Response.cpp:3:1: error: uninitialized reference member ‘Response::request’ [-fpermissive]
make[2]: *** [build/Release/GNU-Linux-x86/Response.o] Error 1
```

Comment: You have a ton of mistakes. First, class definitions end in a semicolon. And why `Request request = Request(socket);`? Just write `Request request(socket);`. Further, if those are your _entire_ headers, then you forgot to write any includes whatsoever.

Comment: Downvoted because you don't even post the errors

Comment: what exactly is the error you are facing now?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Request request = Request(socket); is probably not the biggest mistake in here though. :-)

Comment: sorry I was realy tired my PC was dead and I was writting this from a mobile :D so much for a nice day :) anyway thx for you advice but still this is not solving my problem, I did edit the message hope this will help you explain to me why this code doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make an assignment to a reference member variables as opposed to initialize that in the initializer list. That is illegal, and that is why you are hitting errors.

You should write the following constructor in the header:

```
class Request;

// ...

class Response {
public:
    Response(Request &r) : request(r) {}

    // ...

private:
    Request &request;
};
```

Although, you may wish to consider using pointers instead of reference member variables.